# The Linux tag wiki info page is a mess. How can we fix it?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

At the top of [the Linux tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info):

> Linux is a Unix-like computer operating system

at the bottom:

> Properly "Linux" is the operating system kernel, rather than the entire operating system

It's a mess, in my opinion. I know it's big naming holywar "linux vs gnu linux". Some people say "Linux" some people say "GNU Linux" but not freaking spaces and tabs in the same code!

What do you think about it? I personally respect GNU Linux but I don't understand how you call it Linux and then say that you call it not proper.

Comment: As far as I know, "Linux (OS) vs Linux (Kernel)" is totally unrelated to "Linux vs GNU/Linux". As "GNU/Linux" only says that it completely relies on the GNU toolchain.

Comment: I mean exactly what you point first "Linux(OS) vs GNU/Linux (OS)" just in another words

Comment: _"Questions about the internals of the Linux kernel or regarding writing Linux kernel modules should be tagged linux-kernel."_ and _"Properly "Linux" is the operating system kernel"_...

Comment: Personally I'd replace "Properly" with "Strictly speaking" and be done with it. Sounds  more correct to me and I see nothing else wrong with that sentence.

Comment: It is a mess, and the `what's with GNU/Linux` makes it even more of a mess. There's some great information in there, but the wiki should be re-written. It also needs to point more prominently to `linux-kernel`, for questions specifically about the Linux kernel. I would not mind seeing some answers that were heavy edits of the info section so something better can be collaborated upon and put in place.

Comment: In fact, this is a _great_ area to have a Wikipedia-like 'disambiguation' section at the top. "Linux can refer to the Linux kernel, or a UNIX like operating system as a whole ... combined with the GNU operating system and programs contributed by programmers from all over the world" .. or something like that. If I don't get around to writing it, I'll drop a bounty here to encourage someone else to do it.

Comment: @TimPost i have suggested an edit to the wiki for linux tag..

Comment: @RishiKalia: Nice edit.

Comment: Fun thing about meta and issues with tag wikis:  If you're not online the exact instant someone sees the issue, someone will have fixed it by then.  It looks like a solid edit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU demands recognition and IMHO, they are not wrong in asking, so although I am too small to talk on this topic..

So, according to the GNU folks, terming the whole operating system as *Linux* is a mistake as it doesn't signifies anywhere the contribution that they have done to the OS..

Under the Linux tag, [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), it is beautifully written that:

> **What's with "GNU/Linux"?**
>
> Properly "Linux" is the operating system kernel, rather than the
>   entire operating system, and most Linux systems use the kernel plus a
>   host of userspace utilities provided by the GNU project. In
>   recognition of this fact some people prefer to call the system
>   "GNU/Linux".

The above lines suffices it all..

Also, to add here *it's a matter of preference* how you name it and a vast majority of people name it *Linux* even though they regard the GNU contribution...

Comment: So... I read whole answer and understand all the points but try to forget about everything you know about linux and read wiki page again. When you provide some iformation you must make a choise what to say. What will you feel if I say you that "java" is NOSQL database, but properly it's programming language.

Comment: It always will be a matter of preference for common people what they wish to choose as the term to denote the whole OS and it always will be GNU/Linux when developers would look at it..

Comment: approving answer for your wiki edition.

Answer (score 0):

My proposed fix is to remove it.

No one who belongs on stackoverflow.com needs a tag wiki to tell them what Linux is. Why not spare all the angst and empty it?

Comment: "it" being the "offending" parts or the entire wiki?